# sicp section 4.1.6

Tags: text, sicp

I need some help in understanding the material in SICP's section 4.1.6 on Internal definitions.

I understand the problem raised when mutually recursive functions are defined. But i dont understand how it is solved by transforming the following lambda expression

```
(lambda <vars >
  (define u <e1 >)
  (define v <e2 >)
  <e3 >)
```

into:

```
(lambda <vars >
  (let ((u ’*unassigned*)
        (v ’*unassigned*))
    (set! u <e1 >)
    (set! v <e2 >)
    <e3 >))
```

Can someone help me out here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `<e1>` tries referring to `v` in the first form, it fails -- `v` is not defined (not *yet*, but the **not** part is the important one). But in the second form, `v` **is** *defined* by the time you get to `<e1>` (though not yet *assigned* -- but that's ok!-).